# Volume between sphere and cone

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, change-of-variable

I'm having some problems trying to solve this type of problems. I'm asked to find the volume between the cone
$
y^2\sin^2{a} = (x^2+z^2)\cos^2{a}
$
and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I suppose that I will have to use spherical coordinates (for example, $\rho=b$ substituting on the sphere equation) and find out the limits of integration considering that $dV = \rho^2 \sin \phi d\phi d\theta d\rho$ but I don't know how to procede. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should make an attempt. You know how to write $x, y, z$ in spherical coordinates? Then use that to convert equations of the given surfaces in spherical coordinates. Find intersection of the surfaces. You can try it in cylindrical coordinates if you are more comfortable with that. Please use some numerical values to visualize it in 3D coordinates if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to set-up in Cartesian, before considering a conversion to polar or spherical.

Substitute $y^2 =\tan^2 a(x^2 + z^2)$ into the equation of the sphere to find the intersection of the two surfaces.

$\sec^2 a(x^2 + z^2) = b^2$

$2\int_{-b\cos a}^{b\cos a}\int_{-\cos a \sqrt{b^2-z^2}}^{\cos a\sqrt{b^2-z^2}}\int_{\tan a\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{b^2-z^2-x^2}} \ dy\ dx\ dz$

Okay, this doesn't look so bad.  We can keep going in Cartesian, or we can convert to polar or spherical.

Polar

$x = r\cos \theta\\z=r\sin\theta\\y=y$

$y^2 = r^2\tan^2 a\\
y^2 = b^2 - r^2\\
r = b\cos a$

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b\cos a}\int_{r\tan a}^{\sqrt{b^2-r^2}} r\ dy\ dr\ d\theta$

Spherical
$x = \rho\cos \theta\sin\phi\\
z=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
y=\rho\cos\phi$

$\rho^2\cos^2\phi\cos^2 a = \rho^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2 a\\
\tan\phi = \cot a$

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}-a}\int_0^b \rho^2\sin\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

or

$x = \rho\cos \theta\cos\phi\\
z=\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
y=\rho\sin\phi$

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^b \rho^2\cos\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

Update -- does the integral via polar equal the integral via spherical?

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b\cos a}\int_{r\tan a}^{\sqrt{b^2-r^2}} r\ dy\ dr\ d\theta\\
2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{b\cos a} r\sqrt{b^2-r^2} - r^2\tan a\ dr\ d\theta\\
2\int_0^{2\pi} -\frac 13 (b^2-r^2)^\frac 23 - \frac 13 r^3\tan a |_0^{b\cos a} d\theta\\
\frac 23 \int_0^{2\pi} b^3 - b^3\sin^3 a - b^3 \cos^2a\sin a d\theta\\
\frac {4\pi}{3}b^3(1-\sin a)$

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^b \rho^2\cos\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta\\
\frac {2}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^{\frac {\pi}{2}} b^3\cos\phi \ d\phi\ d\theta$
\frac {2}{3}\int_0^{2\pi} b^3(1-\sin a) \ d\theta$
\frac {4\pi}{3}b^3(1-\sin a)$

Comment: And why do you use $z = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi$ instead of $z = \rho \cos \phi$

Comment: Because of the alignment of the cone.  Same reason we used $y=y$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: Ok, also you use $y^2 = \tan ^2 a (x^2 + z^2)$ and I think the correct one is $y^2 = \cot ^2 a (x^2+z^2)$.

Comment: And the result I get is different in polar and spherical

Comment: I forgot the 2 factor for the double-cone in my spherical setup.