# Volume and change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I'm working on integration and change of variables. I'm not sure about how to do an exercise by using spherical and cylindrical coordinates. I think I can understand the process just seeing how it works for the spherical ones.

> Calculate the volume of the set between the cone $y^2\sin^2a=(x^2+z^2)\cos^2a$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$.

First, I've replaced $x=r\cdot \sin\theta\cdot \cos\phi$, $y=r\cdot \sin\theta\cdot \sin\phi$ and $z=r\cdot \cos\theta$ in both expressions and I've obtained: $0=-r^2\cdot \sin^2\theta\cdot \sin^2\phi-r^2\cdot \sin^2a$ for the cone and $r=b$ for the sphere.

Then, I thought of finding the intersection between the cone and the sphere:
$y^2=b^2-x^2-z^2\Longrightarrow(b^2-x^2-x^2)\sin^2a=(x^2+z^2)\cos^2a$.

By using $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$, I've got: $b^2\sin^2a=x^2+z^2\Longrightarrow b^2\sin^2a=-b^2\sin^2a=-b^2\sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi-b^2$

I don't know how to go on to obtain the limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$ since I think I have the value of $r$ ($r=b$), and I don't know if it's ok what I've done neither.

Thanks!

Comment: I just answered the exact same question :) Pls check the above link.

Comment: The key is to use $y = r \cos \theta$ instead of $z$ as cone is along y-axis.

Comment: @MathLover I've just checked the link but I still can't see how to get the limits of intgration, that's my main problem.

Comment: first put $y = r \cos\theta$ and do the working again. Rest I will help with.

Comment: @MathLover it looks better! $\tan^2a(1-\sin^2\theta)=\sin^2\theta$ from the cone expression.

Comment: yes so what does that mean for value of $\theta$?

Comment: @MathLover $\theta=a$ so how do I choose the limits of integration for $\theta$?

Comment: So $0 \leq \theta \leq a$, right? Think of a ray from origin to the sphere. The ray is bound by the cone so that is your limit of $\theta$.

Comment: @MathLover ok, so we have $0\le r\le b$, $0\le\theta\le a$ and $0\le\phi\le2\pi$. I guess we have to choose the whole circle because there's no condition on $\phi$.

Comment: This very question was asked yesterday. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143383/volume-between-sphere-and-cone/4143444#4143444

Comment: @DougM now I recall... in fact I see I commented yesterday asking the OP to make an attempt and today I see the same person ask the question again. It came across as a good question and has upvotes.

Comment: @DougM oh thanks so much!! I didn't see the question which was posted yesterday.